# Domain name does not appear for everyone

Tags: domain-name-system, port, port-forwarding, domain-name

I have a dynamic ip addresser. I can register a domain with that. I have tried to register a domain name that is only displayed on the computers that are connected to my modem.

For others not.

This is domain name IP I have registered is 192.168.0.122

It seems to me that the problem is port 80
I tried to test ip address with open port check.
But blocked there is a way to open it.
Not in the firewall of the pc or modem I've tried.

Comment: What? This question makes no sense. I don't understand the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address 192.168.0.122 is not routed on the Internet, hence you will be able to connect to this computer only from your local LAN not from outside of it.

Comment: Exactly. Further, to do what you are trying to, you must obtain your public ip, this can be done in numerous ways, for instance with whatsmyip.org 

Once you find it, all firewalls between the internal computer and the outside must allow the port 80 traffic and the router must know where to send traffic that is related to port 80 (Port forwarding).